Are specific brain facts about specific people considered on topic?
I saw this question come up today and I don't know if this is the kind of question we want to encourage here. It's motivation is trivia, rather than learning or knowledge sharing. Is there be a policy on this sort of question? What do other sites do about this?

I understand your concern, but I do not feel we get this sort of questions very often, so a 'default' way of dealing with them might not be needed.

No, there is no policy unique to this kind of question, if I understand what kind of question you're trying to use this as an example of. (There is a meta-question about neurobiology questions though: Are questions about neurobiology on or off topic? the question were off-topic for some clear reason that at least five people (or one moderator) would endorse, it could be put on hold for a custom reason, but I don't see any reason to consider this off-topic.
I don't think "trivia" is a motive, much less one that is distinct from "learning or knowledge sharing", nor do I see a need for concern about users' motives when they are not particularly disruptive. If you feel the question is not useful, you may wish to downvote. Of course its clarity and specificity deserves as much scrutiny as any other question, so those are options for flagging/voting to close too, but I don't see any need in this case, personally.

My thought is that it's loosely related to the question of whether being a genius is related to brain volume. In that sense, it is a bit relevant to this site. That said, I don't think the brain volume of Albert Einstein is especially relevant to this debate. 
